# Grid in vf page

Tags: visualforce, pageblocksection, apexpage, panelgrid, pageblocksectionitem

Hi i want grid behavior in vf; below is the code i am using, but strange behavior is that my tooltip is missing and also label; for that i have used **outputlabel** anyways. How to render **tootltip**? I have used **panelgrid** to get a grid behavior i.e two coloumns, and i will hide that second coloumn section fields based on some condition. If i use normal **pageblocksection** i am getting tooltip and label also, but if i hide second coloumn field in this case **Desc** , the other field **Section2** is coming into place which i do not want. Any suggestions please, to get tooltip or any other alternative way?

```
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Description" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!test.Name}">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="col1, col2, col3, col4" cellpadding="">
                    <apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:outputLabel> Name</apex:outputLabel>
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                    <apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!test.Overall__c}" />
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                    <apex:panelGroup> 
                        <apex:outputLabel>Desc </apex:outputLabel> 
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                    <apex:panelGroup rendered="{!IF( hidingfield == true, true, false )}">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!test.Over__c}" />
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                    <apex:panelGroup> 
                        <apex:outputLabel>Section2</apex:outputLabel> 
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                    <apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!test.Ov__c}" />
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageblockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

For `<apex:panelGrid>` you can use the "**title**" attribute to show the tooltip when the user's mouse pointer hovers over this component.
As per what I see in the above code I think you also have to put the rendered condition on this `<apex:outputLabel>Desc</apex:outputLabel>` line also.

May this will help you.